# How to wrap the ViewPager on DialogFragment

Tags: android

I want to create tabbed dialog, then i try ViewPager because TabHost can't used. But the dialog showed match parent. Can you help me, please.

Comment: post your code what you have tried so far?

Comment: I create view pager inside dialog fragment, it's work. But the view pager can't use wrap content, it's the problem.